# Get last date of modification in database by value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How it is possible to get - when was the last change (by date) -  in
this table:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 02.01.2021 | 10.0 |
| 1 | 03.01.2021 | 15.0 |
| 1 | 04.01.2021 | 25.0 |
| 1 | 05.01.2021 | 25.0 |
| 1 | 06.01.2021 | 25.0 |

Of course I could use clause where and it will works, but i have a lot of rows and for some i don't now exactly day when this happend.

The resault should be:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04.01.2021 | 25.0 |

Comment: does the entry with '05.01.2021' and '06.01.2021' imply that there was some other change or should it be ignored because the value is still the same?

Comment: the value can be only higher from previous or also lower ?

Comment: It should be ignored because the value is still the same

Comment: Value could be also lower

Comment: you can use PARTITION BY on value column, try here https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-partition-by-clause-overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as (
  select 1 as id, date '2021-01-01' as date, 0 as value union all
  select 1, date '2021-01-02', 10 union all
  select 1, date '2021-01-03', 15 union all
  select 1, date '2021-01-04', 25 union all
  select 1, date '2021-01-05', 25 union all
  select 1, date '2021-01-06', 25
)
select id, array_agg(struct(date, value) order by last_change_date desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from (
  select *, if(value != lag(value) over (partition by id order by date), date, null) as last_change_date
  from mytable
)
group by id
```

[image]

Comment: he wants the last change! not the first one

Answer (score 0):

in this scenario I would be using two field in my database "created_at and updated_at" with the type as "timestamp". You may simply fetch your records using OrderBY "updated_at" field.

Answer (score 0):

see what this gives you:

```
 SELECT MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY(value)) AS lastChange 

 FROM Table

 WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query and reproducible example on db-fiddle works. I've also included some additional test records.

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `date` date,
  `value` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_data
  (`id`, `date`, `value`)
VALUES
  ('1', '01.01.2021', '0.0'),
  ('1', '02.01.2021', '10.0'),
  ('1', '03.01.2021', '15.0'),
  ('1', '04.01.2021', '25.0'),
  ('1', '05.01.2021', '25.0'),
  ('1', '06.01.2021', '25.0'),
  ('2', '05.01.2021', '25.0'),
  ('2', '06.01.2021', '23.0'),
  ('3', '03.01.2021', '15.0'),
  ('3', '04.01.2021', '25.0'),
  ('3', '05.01.2021', '17.0'),
  ('3', '06.01.2021', '17.0');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    id,
    date,
    value
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc)  as id_rank
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            m1.date,
            m1.value,
            rank() over (partition by id,m1.value order by date asc)  as id_value_rank,
            CASE
                WHEN (m1.date = (max(m1.date) over (partition by id,m1.value ))) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS is_max_date_for_group,
    CASE
        WHEN (m1.date = (max(m1.date) over (partition by id ))) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS is_max_date_for_id                                 
from 
    my_data m1
) m2
WHERE (m2.is_max_date_for_group = m2.is_max_date_for_id and is_max_date_for_group <> 0 and id_value_rank=1) or (id_value_rank=1 and is_max_date_for_id=0)
) t
              where t.id_rank=1
                         order by id, date, value;
```

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04.01.2021 | 25 |
| 2 | 06.01.2021 | 23 |
| 3 | 05.01.2021 | 17 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dPNnw7wLoaPAZzp6WQPB8d/0)

Answer (score 0):

I actually find that the simplest method is to enumerate the rows by id/date and by id/date/value in descending order.  These are the same for the last group . . . and the rest is aggregation:

```
select id, min(date), value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, value order by date desc) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = seqnum_2
group by id;
```

If you use `lag()`, I would recommend using `qualify` for performance:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      qualify lag(value) over (partition by id order by date) <> value or
              lag(value) over (partition by id order by date) is null
     ) t
qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) = 1;
```

Note:  Both of these work if the value is the same for all rows.  Other methods may not work in that situation.